# How to get index value of an element while onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, indexing, click, this, onmouseover

I am trying to get an element's index number while onmouseover.
I can do this easily with jQuery but native javascript is bulletproof /:

[Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DAFx/1/)

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0];

for(i=0; i<ele.children.length;i++){
    ele.children[i].onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.background='red';
        alert(i);//can't get the value
    }
}

<ul class="sample">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Life's too short to not do this in jQuery!

Comment: bulletproof? or do you mean bulletfast? I wouldn't call it bulletproof...but maybe you mean something different

Comment: @LeeTaylor, True, but I expect jQuery users to know how it can be done without jQuery, or their code will be poor.

Comment: @gdoron yeah, thats my purpose here (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `i` was overridden already, store it in an attribute:

```
ele.children[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.background='red';
    alert(this.getAttribute('data-index'));
};
ele.children[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rgHBD/)

Or use a closure:

```
ele.children[i].onmouseover = (function (index) {
    return function () {
        this.style.background = 'red';
        alert(index);
    };
}(i));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9JNgh/)

Answer (score 4):

Use a immediate function to fix the value of i for the current iteration:

```
for(i=0; i<ele.children.length;i++){
    (function(i) {
        ele.children[i].onmouseover = function() {
            this.style.background='red';
            alert(i);
        }
    }(i));
}
```

Here is a updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sD4aW/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function callback(i) {
    return function() {
        this.style.background = "red";
        alert(i);
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < ele.children.length; i++) {
    ele.children[i].onmouseover = callback(i);
}
```